# Retrieving iframe src on one page from a second page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Page 1:

```
<iframe id="ifrm1" src="anything.com"></iframe>
```

Page 2:

```
<iframe id="ifrm1" src="page1"></iframe>
```

I want to use page 1 iframe (ifrm1) src value "anything.com" in Page 2, e.g I want to display "anything.com" in page 2 text box

please help me !!

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: PLease let us know how you are redirecting to page 2?

Comment: i want to get page 1 ifrm1 src value in Page 2 .....plz help

Comment: hey,kiran  in page 1 code is  < iframe id="ifrm1" src="anything.com"> < /iframe>     and page 2 code is < iframe id="ifrm1" src="page1"> < /iframe> but i want use page1 iframe src value i.e. anything.com  in page 2  ......................e.g i want to display anything.com in page 2 text box  ....plz help

Comment: user919396 dude it can be achieved. But tell us that how you go to page 2? Whether you redirect from page 1?

Comment: user919396 - I've updated your question with the information from your last comment, but it's still a bit unclear what you want to do. Can you confirm that your Page 2 has an iframe, the `src` of which is your Page 1, so from Page 2 you want to access the content of Page 1 _as loaded in the Page 2 iframe_ to see, in turn, what Page 1's iframe `src` is? And are both Page 1 and Page 2 _your_ pages on the same domain?

Comment: hey , i m not redirect page1 and page2 i m just using ifrmae to pass src value ....as page2.htm  < iframe id="ifrm1" src="page1.htm"> < /iframe>  and page1.htm as < iframe id="ifrm1" src="anything.com/welcome.php"> < /iframe> ...............i want to get page 1  iframe src value i.e. anything.com/welcome.php in page2

Comment: yes.. Page1.htm and Page2.htm pages are in the same domain...page2.htm use iframe i.e. src value is page1.htm and page1.htm also use iframe that contain src value is src="anything.com" ......and i want use "anything.com" in page2.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/iframe/page2.html):

```
function get_nested_iframe_src() {
    var f = document.getElementById('ifrm1');
    var ifc;
    if ( f.contentDocument ) {
        ifc = f.contentDocument; //DOM
    } else {
        ifc = f.contentWindow; //IE
    }
    var nested_if = ifc.getElementById('ifrm1');
    return nested_if.src;
}
```